# WebView too slow

Tags: performance, android-webview, android

I have an app that loads a page from my server inside of a webview. In my app, I have a native menu that reloads my webview with a new page when clicked.

My insane problem is that after navigate within the app clicking on  menu more then 5 times, the webview become reaaally slow. Doesn't matter which link and even if I try to reopen a previously page, is still slow.

I tried to use this in my android-manifest file:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

I also tried to deactivate the cache, doing this:

```
myWebView.webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Anyone has an idea about my problem? What can be?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code if you have your own webviewclient?

Comment: I don't have my own webviewclient, I use chromium... "myWebView" above was just an example

Comment: May I know the purpose of using the hardwareAccelerated here?
Because it may consume space in RAM. It might be a reason of slowing down your webview

Comment: Just tested setting False and nothing changed. Really crazy :P

Answer (score 0):

Was a memory leak problem! I had to call these functions before load a new url, otherwise, the garbage collector seems not work.

```
mWebView.removeAllViews();
mWebView.clearView();
mWebView.destroy();
```